# static tags not getting displayed on page load having knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table whose headers are getting populated dynamically using foreach and data binding.I have mentioned one static element "hello" also inside  tag but on page loads Hello is getting replaced with data-bind text. why not both hello and data-bind text is displayed together.

```
demo.html : html table having foreach binding and static content
====================================================================
<table cellspacing="0"  style="width: 100%;">     
    <thead>       
        <tr class="headerRow" data-bind="foreach:tableHeader">
            <th class="headerElement " w="3" style="width: 12%;" data-bind="text:$data.header">Hello</th>
        </tr>     
    </thead>
</table>
```

On doing Inspect Element for one of table header column , code is coming as below:

Patient Name

Kindly tell me why hello is replaced for-each data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the `text` data binding works.

> Knockout sets the element’s content to a text node with your parameter
>   value. Any previous content will be overridden.

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html

If you want to have more than one piece of text you can apply the `text` binding to a child element such that:

```
<th class="headerElement " w="3" style="width: 12%;">
<span data-bind="text:$data.header"></span> Hello</th>
```

Comment: suppose if i want to add id to <th> same as the value of $data.header then how can we achieve it dynamically.

Comment: `data-bind="attr {id: $data.header}"`

Comment: Although you should really ask that as a separate question and mark this one as accepted :)

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you. Remember to hit the tick beside my answer to mark this as accepted. Cheers!